# Login from QSQLITE database

Tags: c++, qt, authentication, sqlite

I'm trying to create Login window, but when I try to log in there is a message that I created telling that database is not opened. Sometimes just nothing happens like the button was not coded at all. I have the database in the same catalog with my project.Please help.

```
login::login(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::login)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    Konta = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
    Konta.setDatabaseName("storage.sqlite");
    QFileInfo checkFile("storage.sqlite");
}

login::~login()
{
    delete ui;
    //  Konta.close();
}

void login::on_exit_clicked()
{
    exit(0);
}

void login::on_login_2_clicked()
{
    QString Username, Password;
    Username=ui->username->text();
    Password=ui->password->text();

    if(!Konta.isOpen()) {
        QMessageBox::warning(this,"BŁąd","Brak połączenia z bazą!");
    }
    if(Konta.open()) { {
        QSqlQuery query;
        query.prepare("select * from users where Login='"+ Username +"' and Haslo='"+ Password +"'");
        if(query.exec()) {
            int x=0;
            while(query.next()) {
                x++;
            }

            if(x==1) {
                ui->stan->setText("zalogowano");
            }
            if (x<1) {
                ui->stan->setText("Zle dane");
            }
            if(x>1) {
                ui->stan->setText("zleee");
            }
        }
    } }
}
```

Comment: In title and tags its `MySQL` .. in code its `QSQLITE`  .. or am i missing something?

Comment: What does `checkFile` say, is the database found?

Comment: I have added 
if(checkFile.isFile())
    {
        if(Konta.open()){ui->stan->setText("Working");}
    }
just below check file and now it says "Working" but when i try to log in nothing happens just like the button was not codded

Comment: Why is that not included in your intial post? It's missing. IIRC `QFileInfo::isFile`does not check if the file exists. It does just check whether it's a file or directory, use QFileInfo::exists. If exists is true, we will talk further.

Comment: It exists but then when I try to log in there shows dialog from this line if(!Konta.isOpen()){QMessageBox::warning(this,"BŁąd","Brak połączenia z bazą!");}

Comment: so QFileInfo::exists is true, right?

Comment: if(checkFile.exists())
    {
       ui->stan->setText("Working");
    } 
I have added that

Comment: Try `Konta.setDatabaseName(qApp->applicationDirPath()
                    + QDir::separator()
                    + "storage.sqlite" );` - Do you see anything useful in your debug output? (i. e. QSQLITE driver not loaded..?)

Comment: Same again- label says "Working" but when i try to log for the first time  if(!Konta.isOpen()) this happens and on second and more attempts nothing happens

Comment: I have modified it- added button just to see if its opened and every time i push it it says closed 
void login::on_register_2_clicked()
{
    if(Konta.isOpen()){ui->stan->setText("open");}
    if(!Konta.isOpen()){ui->stan->setText("closed");}
}

Comment: Now i replaced it with another function and i have "Open" label now 
 if(Konta.isValid()){ui->stan->setText("open");}
so does it mean i have some problem with the drivers?

Comment: budyb : Is your database called "storage.sqlite"? It is possible that it is not able to locate the file? Try the absolute path to the library and check. Also, You did read the documentation and add sql module to your project? 
Please reproduce the exact warning on error you get in future.

Comment: Database called "storage.sqlite" is in the same folder with whole project, when i add whole path nothing changes. Every time i try to login i have dialog from this line of code
 if(!Konta.isOpen()){QMessageBox::warning(this,"BŁąd","Brak połączenia z bazą!"); ui->stan->setText("closed");}

Comment: It needs to be in the same place as your binary (release) or (debug) folder most likely, but QFileInfo::exists was true, so the database is found.

Comment: yes, but also QSqlDatabase::isValid()  returns true
and in pro file i have  QT       += core gui sql

Comment: At the beginning of the program everything is OK but later comes the problem when I try do anything with database

Comment: I have modified a bit of my code 
   


   QSqlQuery query;

      query.prepare("SELECT DISTINCT email FROM users WHERE Login = :Username AND Haslo = :Password");
   query.bindValue(":Login", Username);
    query.bindValue(":Haslo", Password);

      
And now if i try to log in i get messages:
      
QSqlQuery::exec: database not open
QSqlQuery::prepare: database not open